# Django CMS unable to add a child to a nested plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

For some reason I can't seem to add a child plugin:

[image]

I want to achieve the following hierarchy:

- Faq row

  - Faq column

    - Faq

However when I press the plus sign of the column nothing happens and I am not able to drag the **Faq** plugin within the **Faq column**. Any idea?

My plugins definitions:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import FaqPluginModel


class FaqRowPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = u'Faq Row'
    module = _("Fundbox")
    render_template = "faq_row.html"
    cache = False
    allow_children = True


class FaqColumnPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = u'Faq Column'
    module = _("Fundbox")
    render_template = "faq_column.html"
    cache = False
    allow_children = True
    require_parent = True


class FaqPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = u'Faq'
    module = _("Fundbox")
    model = FaqPluginModel
    render_template = "faq.html"
    cache = False


plugin_pool.register_plugin(FaqRowPlugin)  # register the plugin
plugin_pool.register_plugin(FaqColumnPlugin)  # register the plugin
plugin_pool.register_plugin(FaqPlugin)  # register the plugin
```